# nodejs pass a buffer from one server to another

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. I have a nodejs server listening on ports 8082 and 8084. Only one client connects to the first port. I want to send a binary stream sent to the first port to browsers connected to the second port. Is passing a buffer the right way? Am I doing it correctly?

```
var b = new Buffer(2048);
var liveServer = require('http').createServer( function(req, res) {

    console.log( 'Stream Connected: ' + req.socket.remoteAddress  );

    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
      , "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
      , "Accept-Ranges": "bytes"  });

    res.write(b);
}).listen(8084);


// HTTP Server to accept incomming MP4 Stream
var streamServer = require('http').createServer( function(request, response) {

                request.on('data', function(data){
                        b.copy(data);

                });
}).listen(8082);
```

Comment: right now you have one node js server listening to two different ports, what are you trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: I have a streaming client which connects on one port and browsers which connect on the other. I want to pass a mp4 stream to browsers thru the client which connects on the first port. I am writing the data from the streaming client to a buffer. Am I doing it correctly?